# Overriding validate method in boost not working with style set

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to override the [*validate*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2445062) method in `boost::program_options` in order to parse a dotted ip address. I also need to parse arguments with just one dash before the option. To do so I set the flag `po::command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short`. When I add the flag the validate method doesn't get called. If I don't set it works fine. Can someone either indicate the problem or suggest a workaround?

Here's my code:

```
struct in_addr MCAST_ADDR;

void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values, in_addr* target_type, int)
{
    printf("validate\n");
    std::string const& mcast_addr = boost::program_options::validators::get_single_string(values);

    if (!mcast_addr.empty())
        if (inet_aton(mcast_addr.c_str(), &MCAST_ADDR) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid address!\n");
    }
    v = boost::any(MCAST_ADDR);
}

namespace po = boost::program_options;

void parse_args(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    try
    {
        po::options_description desc("Options:");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "Help screen")
            ("a", po::value<in_addr>()->required(), "MCAST_ADDR");

        po::variables_map vm;
        po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
                      .options(desc).
                      .style(po::command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short) /* the problematic line */
                      .run(), vm);

        po::notify(vm);

    }
    catch (const po::error &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    parse_args(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the code? What are the actual command line arguments?

Comment: As to calling the code, I've updated the answer. I want to call this program like this `./program_name -a 239.10.11.12`

Comment: Thanks. I think I've got the explanation for the problem, and it's likely a problem in Boost. I'll post in a bit. Say, 30 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general problem is that your option doesn't have a short name. Yes, the "long name" is only a single character, but that's still considered the long name.

To allow the long option to be disguised as a short one use [`allow_long_disguise`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html#boost.program_options.command_line_style.style_t.allow_long_disguise).

Next up, to allow short options in any way, you'll have to make up your mind about how you want option arguments to be presented (`--a=value` or `--a value`).

You'll find out that you failed to make this choice because sometimes the library gives you a runtime diagnostic. E.g.:

```
.style(po::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise | po::command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short)
```

Leads to:

- `boost::program_options misconfiguration: choose one or other of 'command_line_style::long_allow_next' (whitespace separated arguments) or 'command_line_style::long_allow_adja    cent' ('=' separated arguments) for long options.`

Now, the simplest way to fix the omission is to just build on the default behaviour:

```
.style(po::command_line_style::default_style
    | po::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise
    | po::command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short)
```

Now you can pass the whole plethora of options:

```
./a.out /a 239.10.11.12
./a.out /a=239.10.11.12
./a.out -a 239.10.11.12
./a.out -a=239.10.11.12
./a.out --a 239.10.11.12
./a.out --a=239.10.11.12
```

All print

```
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
```

### BONUS

Let's use Boost to parse and validate the IP address!

```
using ip_address = boost::asio::ip::address;

namespace boost { namespace asio { namespace ip {
    void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values, ip_address* /*target_type*/, int) {
        std::string const& mcast_addr = boost::program_options::validators::get_single_string(values);

        auto address = ip_address::from_string(mcast_addr);

        if (!address.is_multicast())
            throw std::invalid_argument("address not multicast: " + address.to_string());

        v = address;
    }
} } }
```

This way, if we pass a non-multicast address, we will flag it as an error and report it:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  address not multicast: 240.10.11.12
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9accdd7dcc307dab)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/address.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using ip_address = boost::asio::ip::address;

namespace boost { namespace asio { namespace ip {
    void validate(boost::any& v, const std::vector<std::string>& values, ip_address* /*target_type*/, int) {
        std::string const& mcast_addr = boost::program_options::validators::get_single_string(values);

        auto address = ip_address::from_string(mcast_addr);

        if (!address.is_multicast())
            throw std::invalid_argument("address not multicast: " + address.to_string());

        v = address;
    }
} } }

namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  try {
    po::options_description desc("Options:");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help,h", "Help screen")
        ("a", po::value<ip_address>()->required(), "MCAST_ADDR")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(desc)
            .style(po::command_line_style::default_style
                | po::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise
                | po::command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short)
            .run(), vm);

    po::notify(vm);

    std::cout << "Parsed: " << vm["a"].as<ip_address>() << std::endl;

} catch (const po::error &ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Which also shows all the test cases:

```
+ ./a.out /a 239.10.11.12
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
+ ./a.out /a=239.10.11.12
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
+ ./a.out -a 239.10.11.12
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
+ ./a.out -a=239.10.11.12
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
+ ./a.out --a 239.10.11.12
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
+ ./a.out --a=239.10.11.12
Parsed: 239.10.11.12
```

And

```
+ ./a.out /a 240.10.11.12
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  address not multicast: 240.10.11.12
bash: line 11: 31582 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out $options
+ ./a.out /a=240.10.11.12
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  address not multicast: 240.10.11.12
bash: line 11: 31585 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out $options
+ ./a.out -a 240.10.11.12
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  address not multicast: 240.10.11.12
bash: line 11: 31587 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out $options
+ ./a.out -a=240.10.11.12
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  address not multicast: 240.10.11.12
bash: line 11: 31589 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out $options
+ ./a.out --a 240.10.11.12
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  address not multicast: 240.10.11.12
```

Comment: Turns out /not/ a boost bug. At best, it might be possible to give some more diagnostics about style combinations. I might not understand all the possible combinations well enough to judge that. I think it's basically "alright". E.g. things do work wihout `allow_long_disguise` iff you supply the short option name (`"a,a"`) - just not with all the forms that apply to long options.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That's awesome! Do you think there is a way to only parse the single dash?

Comment: Sure. Just tweak the style: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0b801fc3f396817 (and supply the short name, of course). Now /only/ "-a 239.10.11.12" is ok